# how to slider gallery convert in php code with slider image and their thumbs image

Tags: php

I am using this slider gallery. i have problem while showing thumbs of images.
i used while loop only on UL and li tags, when i end while loop after thumbs. it will show all images in main image box.. can any one tell me how i can use this gallery in my php code

```
    <div class="image-gallery">
     <?php  if($pic_count > 0){ ?>
      <div id="wowslider-container1">
        <div class="ws_images">
          <?php while(!$rs_img_gallery->EOF) { ?>
          <ul>
            <li><img src="<?php echo MYSURL;?>img.gallery/<?php echo $rs_img_gallery->fields['image'] ?>" alt="" id="wows1_0"/></li>
         </ul>
            <?php $rs_img_gallery->MoveNext();
                } // end while(!$rs_dc_gallery->EOF) ?> 
              </div>
                <div class="ws_thumbs">
                <div>
                    <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo MYSURL;?>img.gallery/<?php echo $rs_img_gallery->fields['image'] ?>" alt="" width="120" height="90"/></a>      
                </div>
                </div>
              </div>
           <?php  }else{
            echo "<div class='notification information png_bg' style='width:90%;'>
     <div>
            ".$infomsg['msg164']."
             </div>
             </div>";
            }?>
           </div>
```

Comment: css can't post what can i don as i have short time

Answer (score 0):

You should take the <UL> out of the while loop

```
 <div class="ws_images">
    <ul>
    <?php   while(!$rs_img_gallery->EOF) { ?>
        <li>
            <img src="<?php echo MYSURL;?>img.gallery/<?php echo $rs_img_gallery->fields['image'] ?>" alt="" id="wows1_0"/>
        </li>
    <?php 
    $rs_img_gallery->MoveNext();
    } // end while(!$rs_dc_gallery->EOF)
    ?>
    </ul> 
 </div>
```

Comment: whats the problem i cant paste css thats very bad i have limited time  and cant indent here... there must be autpm,ativally format software in this stake over flow

Comment: user1788978 thats not the problem ul out side the loop but may be u missed my thumbs code 1st see that then tell me ul dosn't problem problem in this <div class="ws_thumbs">
                <div>
                    <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo MYSURL;?>img.gallery/<?php echo $rs_img_gallery->fields['image'] ?>" alt="" width="120" height="90"/></a>      
                </div>
                </div>